# java print stream and printwriter

Tags: java

I am stuck on why my program is not working, I am trying to print to a file however, where it says `student[i].listCourses(System.out);` I actually need it to print to the test.txt file also but I tried putting in outputFile and it didn't work

```
   System.out.println("Please Enter A FileName");
  // Create a PrintWriter object and open the file.
  PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("test.txt");

  // Get data and write it to the file.
  // Continue reading till a blank line is entered
  int i=0;  
  do
  {

    while ((student[i] != null)&&(i <= student.length)){
        student[i].addCourse(course[i]);
        outputFile.println(student[i].toString());
        student[i].listCourses(System.out);
        i++;
    }
```

and this is how listcourses is declared

```
public void listCourses(PrintStream p) {
        for (Course crs: courses)
            if (crs != null)
                p.println(crs);
    }
```

Comment: Have you closed the stream after operations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an issue

```
while ((student[i] != null)&&(i <= student.length)){
```

lets assume that i == student.length, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your code does not compile for you at the moment.  The issue is that your `outputFile` is a `PrintWriter` while System.out is a `PrintStream`.  These are not interchangeable.  Check out the inheritance hierarchy on each documentation page:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

If you need to use the same function for both objects, you'll have to reconsider what you're passing in (e.g. an `OutputStream` with `System.out` and `FileOutputStream` instead) or make two functions, one that takes in a `PrintWriter` and one that takes in a `PrintStream`.